# How to dynamically add elements to MixItUp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, append

I was trying to append new DOM (MIX) elements in mixItUp based on AJAX calls, but it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I searched a lot and after 2 hours found the solution at https://github.com/patrickkunka/mixitup/issues/149

I wanted to share it with others, so they will not spend the time that I spent.

The solution is to destroy the whole mixItUp, before appending the new element, and load mixItUp again, after that.

```
$('#mixItUpContainer').mixItUp('destroy');
var mixDiv = $('<div></div>')
    .attr({ "data-myorder" : numberOfMixDIVs })
    .addClass("mix");
$("#mixItUpContainer").append(mixDiv);
numberOfMixDIVs++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you also find useful this answer I found on official Mixitup support forum.

**First:**
Setup your ajax request. This one happens to be a very simple example.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/some/url.html",
    dataType: "html"
}).done( function ( html ) {
     // When ajax request is done do some stuff.
});
```

**Second**:
The response you will get back will be a string of html. You then have to parse that string, get the DOM nodes out of it and turn it into a jQuery collection that Mixitup can work with. In the Mixitup documentation there is an Append method, it requires a jQuery collection to be passed.

Side Note: I ran into an issue when I was converting the string into DOM nodes that I also got text nodes back. In the following example I show you how to strip the text nodes out because they are not needed.

So in the .done callback do the following:

```
function convertHTML ( html ) {
    var newHtml = $.trim( html ),
            $html = $(newHtml ),
            $empty = $();

    $html.each(function ( index, value ) {
        if ( value.nodeType === 1) {
            $empty = $empty.add ( this );
        }
    });

    return $empty;
};
```

**1. The Variables**

- newHtml, Trim the whitespace out of the string so we can actually
  parse it correctly.
- $html, wrap the whole thing in jQuery so we use .each to iterate over
  each node.
- $empty, create a blank jQuery object that we are going to use as the
  new collection.

**2. The Each Function: *$html.each…, loop over all the nodes***

- if, if the node type is a DOM node ( 1 ) $empty, set $empty back to
  its self and use the add method to add the new DOM node / jQuery
  object to the collection.
- *Note that it has to be done the way described or it won’t work. $empty,add(); without the proceeding $empty = will not work.*

**Third**:
Use Mixitup’s append method NOT jQuery’s, to throw the elements into the page.

```
$('#mix-up-list').mixItUp('append', $html);
```

**So all together now:**

```
function convertHTML ( html ) {
    var newHtml = $.trim( html ),
            $html = $(newHtml ),
            $empty = $();

    $html.each(function ( index, value ) {
        if ( value.nodeType === 1) {
            $empty = $empty.add ( this );
        }
    });

    return $empty;
};
```

and request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/some/url.html",
    dataType: "html"
}).done( function ( html ) {
    $html = convertHTML( html );
    $('#mix-up-list').mixItUp('append', $html); 
});
```

**Original link:**
https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/support/topic/ajax-example/

Comment: I changed my answer, added more details, not only link